# What is meant by whereRaw in PHP Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I'm unsure what `whereRaw` is in PHP Laravel framework. Could you provide good and easily understandable example, please?

Answer (score 48):

`WhereRaw()` is a function of Laravel query builder which puts your input as it is in the SQL query's where clause.

Think of it as the `where()` function whose input argument will not be processed before inserting into queries.

See the example below:

```
$Query = DB::table('some_table')->where('YEAR(date)', 'YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)');
```

In this Laravel will resolve your arguments to build a query. Which will result in the following query because your input will be treated as some `field` and its its `value` :

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `YEAR(date)` = "YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)"
```

Which is not desired.

And now if you use `whereRaw` like:

```
$Query = DB::table('some_table')->whereRaw('YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)');
```

Now Laravel put this where clause as it is in your query, like below:

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Hope it helped (:

Comment: great explanation!

Answer (score 30):

**WhereRaw:** Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query. These expressions will be injected into the query as strings.

If you are unable to generate the query you need via the fluent interface, feel free to use `whereRaw()`

Ex:

```
$users = User::whereRaw('age > ? and votes = 100', array(25))->get();
```

which is equals to:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > 25 AND votes = 100";
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 8):

In laraval we use query builder. But Sometime you need to execute raw sql query.

So you can inject it to `whereRaw` as this example :

```
whereRAW('YEAR(event_datetime) =?', [$year])
```