# search date when date is stored in the string format in db

Tags: php, laravel, database, query-builder

I ma trying to filter data on date but I have stored the date in string format. I have coded it like this but it is not giving any result to me rather throws an error...

```
 // search attendance
    public function searchAttendance(Request $request)
    {
        $site_details = tbl_site::where("site_name", $request->site_name)->first();
        $query = tbl_master_attendance::query();
        $query->where("attendance_site_id", $site_details->site_id);
        $query->where(
            DB::Raw("STR_TO_DATE(attendance_date,'%d-%m-%Y')"),
            Carbon::parse($request->att_date)
        )->get();
        return $query;
        // return tbl_attendance::where("tbl_master_id", $attendance_master->master_attendances_id)->get();
    }
```

Comment: Okay. is there any way to fix the bug ??

Comment: Yes, make the date a proper DATE or DATETIME column

Comment: And did you store the date in the table in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: The Best way is to change it from string to date

Comment: I see a lot of issues here. first, you cant run db raw with where. you need to use whereRaw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927037/what-is-meant-by-whereraw-in-php-laravel-framework.  secondly, it throws what error? we need a lot more info

Comment: You should use model cause model give you flexibility to deal with dates